# Nougat RemoteInput: color of text field

Tags: android-notifications, android-7.0-nougat, remote-input

I've implemented [RemoteInput](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/RemoteInput.html) in my app, but text field area appears with gray background abd I want it blue like this:

[image]

Is there are any way to do this?

UPD: Looks like `colorPrimary` is used for this, but I don't want to change it in whole app, just in notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `setColor` is what I was looking for. It also changes icon and title tint.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
    //....
    .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(ctx, R.color.colorAccent))
```